# Simple math problem

Tags: c#, .net, algorithm, math

I have a dataset containing n values between 0 and m.

Now i want to map this values in the range between min and max. But how do I do that? If i have in every object this method:

```
public double getValue(int min, int max) {
   // return value between min and max;
}
```

This want work I think?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try:

```
return min + (max - min) * (val / m);
```

Answer (score 3):

If you're talking about mapping the range `0..m` to `min..max`, surely that's just a matter of:

```
newval = val * (max - min) / m + min
```

allowing of course for any integer/floating-point gotchas like inadvertent rounding.

The multiplication by `(max - min) / m` will scale it to the correct range and the addition of `min` will give it the correct lower offset.

Comment: This seems to be the thing im looking for

Comment: >>> min, max, m = 5, 10, 100
>>> 6 * (max - min) + min
35 - that's not scaled between `min` and `max`.

Answer (score 2):

This code is a bit more generic (doesn't take only 0-m range, but any original range):

```
public double GetValue(int value, 
                       int min, 
                       int max, 
                       int originalMin, 
                       int originalMax) 
{
   return min + (double)(value - originalMin) * (max - min) / (originalMax - originalMin);
}
// in your case originalMin = 0, and originalMax = m
```

Comment: Forgot to subtract `value` by `originalMin`, fixed